# Windows 7 Enterprise UAC dialog pops under all windows

Tags: uac, windows-7

I have a Windows 7 Enterprise x64 machine both at work and at home for some reason the UAC dialog windows like to pop UNDER all of my windows instead of on top of everything, is this a bug? It's not consistent whether it will pop over or pop under.

Comment: Seen this too. It is annoying to say the least. Same for x86 as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the program that triggers the UAC dialog active, the dialog will pop up.

If some background program triggers the dialog (for instance an installer which you've alt-tabbed away from) the dialog pops under.

At least that's my experience

Comment: Yes that does seem to be the case, is there a solution to it? Or is this just a bug that's classified as a feature?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry. However, I for one am very happy with this feature, as this way UAC doesn't steal focus but just happily blinks on the taskbar. There's a reason I alt-tabbed away, I'll deal with the UAC dialog at my leasure ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** When the uac setting is in one of the two "higher" settings. The screen is suppose to deem, and the only accessible windows is the uac dialog. That's why you should check that its in the settings I have suggested.

Make sure that your uac settings are in the "default" or "always notify" settings.

Comment: The issue isn't that UAC doesn't display the dialog at all the issue is sometimes the dialog will appear underneath everything so an application most likely has just frozen whatever it was doing while waiting for you to press yes to UAC that is buried under all my other windows.

Comment: FWIW UAC is set on the maximum, most secured level.